# Steady State Solution for Carrier Concentration of Intrinsic Silicon in an Electric Field

Tags: semiconductor-physics, steady-state

I'm trying to model carrier action in intrinsic silicon under an applied electric field in one dimension.

Taking $n$ and $p$ to be the concentrations of electrons and holes respectively, I got that

$$\frac{\partial n}{\partial t} = D_n \nabla^2 n + \mu_n \vec{E} \cdot \vec{\nabla}n+r(np-n_i^2)$$
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = D_p \nabla^2 p + \mu_p \vec{E} \cdot \vec{\nabla}p+r(np-n_i^2)$$

Is that correct? Then taking $\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}$ to be zero to get the steady state and reducing to one dimension, I get

$$D_n \frac{d^2 n}{d x^2} + \mu_n E \frac{dn}{dx} + r(np-n_i^2)=0$$
$$D_p \frac{d^2 p}{d x^2} + \mu_p E \frac{dp}{dx} + r(np-n_i^2)=0$$

Is that correct? If so, what initial conditions would I use to numerically solve this equation for a piece of silicon $L$ units long?

Comment: This is pretty difficult. You also need to solve the Poisson equation to provide $E(x)$. The standard approach is to user the Boltzmann approximation and change variables to from carrier densities to quasi-Fermi-levels. Then you need to discretise the equations (FD, FVM or FEM) and include some form of exponential fitting to keep the equations stable when the Peclet's number is large. Then for accurate solutions some form of adaptive mesh refinement should be used. All in all a very tricky problem! Take a look at the pn-junction solvers on nanohub.org they might get you started.